States using Euclidean path integral
I am aware of the cutting of the path integral to define states in quantum field theories, where we do the Euclidean path integral with an unspecified boundary condition defining the cut.
I am trying to understand what happens if we deform the corresponding Lorentzian time slice (cut in the Euclidean path integral) by making part of the slice null. Will it give the same state because this null deformation is not reflected in the corresponding Euclidean setup?
In general, is there a way to quantify how the states change in the Euclidean path integral when we make a deformation of the corresponding Lorentzian slices?
Edit: the "cuts" I am referring to is explained in Section 4.3 of http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/gravity-lectures.pdf. It is basically a spatial slice of the Euclidean manifold on which the path integral is done. However, a null deformation in the corresponding Lorentzian slice won't affect this spatial slice in the Euclidean manifold, so the question is will such a null deformation in the Lorentzian slice give the same state when we do the Euclidean path integral?

Could you please add some math or graphs describing what you mean and imply (even if it is not exact), since using the word "cut" here I am thinking, "unitarity cuts," but I don't think that is what you mean: thanks!

@MathZilla they mean a boundary.

Coment (v3): One assigns a Hilbert space to a spatial slice. The states, be it prepared by the Euclidean path-integral or however else you want, know no time. Therefore the distinction of "Lorentzian time slice" and "Euclidean time slice" is nonsensical. Correspondingly every question or conclusion derived from this distinction is ill-defined.

@ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I am not sure if I understood your remark about associating a Hilbert space to a spatial slice, because in the derivations of Hawking radiation and subsequent literature on black hole thermodynamics we often associate states with null segments like scri^+ or the horizon of a black hole (cf. https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3445). So I would think that the state obtained by a purely spatial slicing and one with spatial+null slicing should not be the same. However, when the Euclidean path integral is done the null part does not seem to play any role. Did I misunderstand something?
